# Pass data to controller method from AuthorizationFilter in ASP.Net Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have implemented a custom `AuthorizationFilter` in my ASP.NET Core Web API. The filter checks for a code in the request header and identifies the `userID` based on the code.

I want this `userID` to be reused in my GET/POST call. How can I transfer data from my `AuthorizationFilter` to my calling method to avoid duplicate database calls?

`AuthorizationFilter` function:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
        string header = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["CODE"].ToString();

        int userID = GetAccessData(header);
        //Want to use this UserID in my calling method
}
```

Calling function in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult UseData(Model modelObj)
{
     // I want to use userID retrieved at filter level here.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> transfer data from my AuthorizationFilter to my calling method

Below is a work demo, I use two options,  you can refer to it.

CustomAuthenticationFilter :

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {  
             //you can use your userID
             //Option 1
            context.HttpContext.Items["userID"] = "1111111";
           
             //Option 2
             var userId = "22222";
             context.RouteData.Values.Add("UserId", userId);
        }
    }
```

Action:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [CustomAuthenticationFilter]
        public IActionResult UseData()
        {
            
            // I want to use userID retrieved at filter level here.
            var userID = HttpContext.Items["userID"];
            var userid2 = RouteData.Values["UserId"];
            return Ok(userID);
        }
```

result:

[image]